# PHP get number of (distinct) data in column

Tags: php, distinct

Hy!

How can I get number of distinct data from column 3 and 6 of my table in my PHP:

```
<?php
```

open text file (first row is of headers which are divided by ;)

```
$fp = fopen('C:\...\usedlicences.txt','r') or die("can't open file");
```

create table with border

```
echo "<table id='MyTable' border='1'>\n";
```

create header row for table with headers

```
echo "<td><b>id</b><td><b>name</b></td><td><b>surname</b></td><td><b>address</b></td><td><b>state</b></td><td><b>phone</b></td><td><b>city</b></td><td><b>date</b></td><td><b>color</b></td>";                          
$length = 1000;
$delimiter = ";";      
$k=1;
```

from file create rows and populate them with data (skip first (header) row) and add first column where id of row is written

```
$csv_line = fgetcsv( $fp, $length, $delimiter); 
while($csv_line = fgetcsv( $fp, $length, $delimiter ) ) {
echo "<tr>";            
echo "<td>$k</td>";
$k++;   
for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {
echo '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';  
}
}
echo "<tr>";   
echo '</table>';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
?>
```

for showing alert how much licences are used (all rows minus header row)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var oRows = document.getElementById('MyTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
var iRowCount = oRows.length-1;
alert('Licences used: ' + ((iRowCount)-1)+'!');
</script>
```

test.txt looks like:

```
id;name;surname;address;state;phone;city;date;color
1;John;Simts;Yellow 12;Greenik;1234567;Mannds;12/3/1234;blue
```

Thanks, greetings

Comment: No, this is my code for showing data form txt in a table using phpm html and javascript. Now I need help with writting down a code, that would count number of distinct surnames (column 3) and phones (column 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your for loop place the following code:

```
if ($i==3) 
   $surname[$csv_line[$i]]++;
else if ($i==6)
   $phone[$csv_line[$i]]++;
```

Then number of distinct records for surnames (column 3) and phones (column 6) would be:

```
count($surname);
count($phone);
```

respectively.

Comment: That is not working for me. I get only one number in echo output and it's calculated as 'number of rows in column (18) * number of columns (9) = 162'

Comment: My answer tries to solve this `How can I get number of distinct data from column 3 and 6`. So if you have in column `surname` 10 entries of which the 4 are unique and in the column `phone` 10 entries of which the 8 are unique then  `count($surname) => 4` and `count($phone) => 8`. If you need something else then please rephrase your question

Comment: Do You maybe know how to sort this table by columns - when I click on choosen header (names of headers would be links), table would sort by that header - column?

Comment: Please mark this as answered and I'll be happy to assist you further on a seperate topic.